# Sending GET and POST AJAX requests at the same time

Tags: javascript, ajax

i just would like to know if it is possible sending GET and POST AJAX requests at the same time and if it is how to do it using the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Thanks all for helping :D

Comment: @Aircule - Sure, i need to send a very long argument to another php page via ajax. The argument i want to send to the php page contains TinyMCE data which can be longer than 2048 characters.

Comment: What's stopping you from using POST only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send the request as a `POST`. An HTTP request can only have one method, but nothing is stopping you from using parameters on a `POST` URL.

If you `POST` to `http://example.com/form?foo=bar`, you'll still be able to access `foo` as a `GET` parameter.

---

Here's an example using jQuery:

```
$.post("http://example.com/form?" + $.param({foo: "bar"}), {text: tinyMCEBody})
```

Without jQuery, that would look more like this:

```
…
request.open("POST","form?foo=bar",true);
request.send("text=" + encodeURIComponent(tinyMCEBody));
…
```

Comment: I know that, but i read that a GET URL cannot be longer than 2048 chars. So i decided to send the TinyMCE area content by POST.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you post an example? I've updated my question with a little bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you'd like to send some query string values along with your POST? Surely it's just a case of appending them the post URL?

Comment: I need to send some short args by GET, and another arg (which can be very long [> 2040 chars] with POST.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just make two instances of the `XMLHttpRequest`? So you could have:

**Get**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp1.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp1.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp1.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**POST**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc2()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp2=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp2.readyState==4 && xmlhttp2.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp2.responseText;
    }
  }
//Set POST params
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";

xmlhttp2.open("POST","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp2.send(params);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc2()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

All I changed was the name of the object `xmlhttp1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` and `xmlhttp2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`

Taken from W3Schools
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: I tried this way, but it's like if the receiving php page doesn't accept the POST parameters. In fact the php page doesn't recognize correctly the parameters.

Comment: So you mean when you try to use two instances of the `XMLHttpRequest` object the destination page did not receive the post variables, but when you used just one instance it worked?

Comment: @Joel Kennedy in my case, any request AJAX send the same values in GET and POST, I just print `$GLOBALS`. Aditionally, your URL is broken (for current year 2021 maybe is https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)